# How do you convert this equation into Latex? I tried to do it and it gave me "undefined control sequence"

Tags: latex, pdflatex

How do you convert this equation into Latex? I tried to do it and it gave me "undefined control sequence"..

The equation I want to produce in my pdflatex:

[image: equation]

***My solution:***

```
$Ker(f) = \{\alpha(0, 1, -1), \alpha \in \R \}$
```

***Error:***

**Undefined control sequence**

Answer (score 1):

`\R` is not a macro which is defined by default. If you would like to use it, you can for example define it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

$\text{Ker}(f) = \{\alpha(0, 1, -1), \alpha \in \R \}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you may want to use ${\rm ker}(f)...$ to better match the style.

Comment: @francesco Thanks for noticing the incorrect kerning! (two letter font commands like `\rm` shouldn't really be used in latex)